# MapView V2 in a ScrollView draws itself over the ActionBar

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, android-scrollview

So, all bad things in the title aside, I've got a `MapView` (and a few other Views) inside of a `ScrollView` (I know, and I've advised a thousand times against putting a MapView in a scrolling container but this is what the client wants) and when I scroll the `ScrollView` up the `MapView` ends up drawing over the `ActionBar`. I set the `zOrderOnTop` to true on the `GoogleMapOptions` that I pass to the constructor of `MapView` which prevents this from happening when I first add the `MapView` to the view hierarchy, but when I navigate away and come back to the app the map is drawn over the ActionBar again.

I have to artificially call the MapView lifecycle events when the MapView is created and placed into the ScrollView because I make a network call, and depending on the data I may or may not need to add a map.

I've been searching on Google and SO for ways to mitigate this and I've come up with nothing. The phones I'm testing on are Android 4.1+ so it should be using the `TextureView` implementation and not the `SurfaceView` implementation of MapView.